# Timestamp each line that's changed when multiple cells are changed together (e.g. using Autofill)

Tags: vba, excel

[Screen shot of what I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fafC.png)

[image]

I want to time stamp each line as a change gets made so I can upload to a central file all lines that have been updated after a certain time. Since one asset might have multiple rows for each sub component, the user can fill in one line and autofill/copy paste to the relevant lines beneath. The rows might not be in a continuous range (e.g. when filtered).

The code I've got works great for changing one cell at a time and it works for a range but incredibly slowly.

This sub is called by worksheet_change shown in full below.

```
    Sub SetDateRow(Target As Range, Col As String)

    Dim TargetRng As Range
    Dim LastCol, LastInputCol As Integer
     With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 24
    End With

     For Each TargetRng In Target.Cells

     If TargetRng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    Else
Application.EnableEvents = False

Cells(TargetRng.Row, LastCol - 2) = Now()
 Cells(TargetRng.Row, LastCol - 1).Value = Environ("username")
Cells(TargetRng.Row, LastCol).Value = Target.Address

End If
Next

       Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

`Target.Cells.Address` returns the range (including non-visible cells), but I can't work out how to split this into individual, visible cells that I can loop through.

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

                On Error GoTo Errorcatch


                Dim TargetRng As Range

                Dim LastCol, LastInputCol, LastRow As Integer
                Dim LastInputColLetter As String
                Dim ContinueNewRow
                With ActiveSheet
                LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 24
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                End With
                LastInputCol = LastCol - 3

                If LastInputCol > 26 Then
                    LastInputColLetter = Chr(Int((LastInputCol - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(((LastInputCol - 1) Mod 26) + 65)
                Else
                    LastInputColLetter = Chr(LastInputCol + 64)
                End If

                 For Each TargetRng In Target.Cells


                    If TargetRng.Row <= 2 Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If


                If TargetRng.Column <= LastInputCol Then

                    SetDateRow Target, LastCol - 3


                    If TargetRng.Count = 1 Then



                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                '
                   Dim cmt As String
                '    If Target.Value = "" Then
                '    Target.Value = " "
                '
                '    End If
                '----------------------------------------------------------------
                If Intersect(TargetRng, Range("AC3:AC10000")) Is Nothing Then ' need to make column into variables in the code based on column name

                 Application.EnableEvents = True
                 Else

                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Cells(TargetRng.Row, "Z") = Now() 'Date booking was made column
                    Cells(TargetRng.Row, "AD").Value = Cells(Target.Row, "AD").Value + 1 ' iteration column

                End If
                '----------------------------------------------------------------

                    If TargetRng.Comment Is Nothing Then
                        cmt = Now & vbCrLf & Environ("UserName") & " *" & TargetRng.Value & "*"
                    Else
                         cmt = Now & vbCrLf & Environ("UserName") & " *" & TargetRng.Value & "* " & TargetRng.Comment.Text
                    End If

                        With TargetRng
                            .ClearComments
                            .AddComment cmt
                        End With


                         End If
                   End If

                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                Next

                Exit Sub

     Errorcatch:
                    MsgBox Err.Description
                        Application.EnableEvents = True


                End Sub
```

Comment: Which address do you want stored for each line when they change multiple cells? The address of the changed cell in that row, or the address of all the cells that were changed (i.e. `Target.Address`)?

Comment: Would you mind publishing your workbook as it will save us a lot of typing and will help to understand your settings.

Comment: have few questions: 1) Are the updates for `Date Change Made`, `Who Made Change` and `Last Cell Changed` always taking place at columns `BG`, `BH` and `BI` respectively?   2) What triggers the updates done at columns `"Z" = Now() 'Date booking was made column` and `"AD").Value = Cells(Target.Row, "AD").Value + 1 ' iteration column`?

Comment: Rory, I would like ideally, the name of the cell changed in that row but it's not a big issue.

Comment: EEM, i'm looking into posting the work book but need to strip out confidential stuff first. I can't work our how you highlight the code parts of your answers, but 1)    Date Change Made, Who Made Change and Last Cell Changed are always in the same relative position. Ideally this won't move from BG, BH and BI but might should user needs change.

Comment: EEM 2) any change to column AC, that's within the specified upper and lower row limit (e.g. not in a blank row at the bottom and not in the header rows)

Comment: your data seems to have headers in which row are they located

Comment: the `iteration column` what's in counting the numbers of cells changed or just adds 1 to whatever value in in the cell at `AD`?

Comment: EEM, the headers are in rows 1 and 2.  the iteration column is counting the number of changes to column AC made on that row. We get charged every time a booking is changed, and the amount is based on the notice given. Therefore column AD "iteration column" counts that times the booked date is changed (in column AC), column Z is when the change was made, so the difference between the date in AC and Z is the notice given and column Z is how many times that booking has been changed.

Comment: So it's a two rows headers now It's correct to assume that the titles `Date Change Made`, `Who Made Change` and `Last Cell Changed` are in row 1? Also do you really need this procedures separated or can I combined both into one?.

Comment: Based on you response about fields `Date Change Made`, `Who Made Change` and `Last Cell Changed`; I guess that it's also possible for columns `AC` `Ad` and `Z` to get moved, if so what's are the tittles of these fields and are they (the titles) also in row 1?

Comment: Can there be more than one change in a row? if so do you want to see all the addresses of just the last one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94014/discussion-between-eem-and-bryony565).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
Sub SetDateRow(Target As Range, Col As String)

    Dim TargetRng             As Range
    Dim LastCol               As Long
    Dim LastInputCol          As Long
    Dim bEvents               As Boolean

    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 24
    End With
    bEvents = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then

        For Each TargetRng In Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas

            Cells(TargetRng.Row, LastCol - 2).Resize(TargetRng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = Now()
            Cells(TargetRng.Row, LastCol - 1).Resize(TargetRng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = Environ("username")
            Cells(TargetRng.Row, LastCol).Resize(TargetRng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = Target.Address

        Next

    Else
            Cells(Target.Row, LastCol - 2).Value = Now()
            Cells(Target.Row, LastCol - 1).Value = Environ("username")
            Cells(Target.Row, LastCol).Value = Target.Address

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = bEvents
End Sub
```

but make sure you call it before or after the loop in your change event, not inside it as you are now!

Comment: Thanks Rory, I've moved it to after the loop in my change event (i'm guessing it was having the loop in the loop which really slowed it down). However, the code above gets stuck in the loop and when i put in       MsgBox Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count  to see why it keeps looping i get an "overflow" error.

Comment: Try using CountLarge rather than  Count if you are changing a **lot** of cells

Comment: Hi Rory, I've only edited 1 cell. so not sure why it's getting stuck. Target.Cells.Count is showing 1, it's the Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) that's getting the overflow.

Comment: Ah yes. If you apply SpecialCells to one cell, it applies to the whole sheet, so need to test that separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some adjustments to your code *(see comments within code)*

This solution assumes the following:

Sample data has a two rows header and fields to be updated have the following titles located at row `1` *(adjust corresponding lines in code if needed)*:

`Date Change Made`, `Who Made Change` and `Last Cell Changed` as per picture provided.

`Booked Date`, `BkdDte Change` and `Iteration` for columns `AC`, `Z` and `AD` respectively *(this names are used for testing purposes, change code to actual names)*

I have also combined both procedures into a common one in order to avoid the inefficient approach of looping twice the cells of the changed range. Let me know if they must remain separated and will do the necessary adjustments.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Wsh As Worksheet, rCll As Range
Dim iDteChn  As Integer, iWhoChn As Integer, iLstCll As Integer
Dim iBkdDte As Integer, iBkdChn As Integer, iBkdCnt As Integer
Dim sCllCmt As String
Dim lRow As Long
On Error GoTo ErrorCatch

    Rem Set Application Properties
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'Improve performance
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'Disable events at the begining

    Rem Set Field Position - This will always returns Fields position
    Set Wsh = Target.Worksheet
    With Wsh
        iDteChn = WorksheetFunction.Match("Date Change Made", .Rows(1), 0)
        iWhoChn = WorksheetFunction.Match("Who Made Change", .Rows(1), 0)
        iLstCll = WorksheetFunction.Match("Last Cell Changed", .Rows(1), 0)
        iBkdDte = WorksheetFunction.Match("Booked Date", .Rows(1), 0)       'Column of field "Booked date" (i.e. Column `AC`)
        iBkdChn = WorksheetFunction.Match("BkdDte Change", .Rows(1), 0)     'Column of field "Booked date changed" (i.e. Column `Z`)
        iBkdCnt = WorksheetFunction.Match("Iteration", .Rows(1), 0)         'Column of field "Iteration" (i.e. Column `AD`)
    End With

    Rem Process Cells Changed
    For Each rCll In Target.Cells
        With rCll
            lRow = .Row

            Rem Exclude Header Rows
            If lRow <= 2 Then GoTo NEXT_Cll

            Rem Validate Field Changed
            Select Case .Column
            Case Is >= iLstCll:                         GoTo NEXT_Cll
            Case iDteChn, iWhoChn, iBkdChn, iBkdCnt:    GoTo NEXT_Cll
            Case iBkdDte
                Rem Booked Date - Set Count
                Wsh.Cells(lRow, iBkdChn) = Now()
                Wsh.Cells(lRow, iBkdCnt).Value = Cells(.Row, iBkdCnt).Value + 1
            End Select

            Rem Update Cell Change Details
            Wsh.Cells(lRow, iDteChn).Value = Now()
            Wsh.Cells(lRow, iWhoChn).Value = Environ("username")
            Wsh.Cells(lRow, iLstCll).Value = .Address

            Rem Update Cell Change Comments
            sCllCmt = Now & vbCrLf & Environ("UserName") & " *" & .Value & "*"
            If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then sCllCmt = sCllCmt & .Comment.Text
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment sCllCmt

        End With

NEXT_Cll:
    Next

    Rem Restate Application Properties
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

ErrorCatch:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Rem Restate Application Properties
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Do let me know of any questions you might have about the resources used in this procedure.